# Implicit conversion not performed on Int

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

In Scala, I want to generate some aliases for basic types, and then implement conversions through a type class. This is both useful for me, and an opportunity to understand type classes. The code is the following:

```
type Index = Int
val Index = Int

type Integer = Int
val Integer = Int

type Real = Double
val Real = Double // to have companion object of Double also be the companion object of Real

trait Convertible[A] {
  def toIndex(a: A): Index
  def toInteger(a: A): Integer
  def toReal(a: A): Real
}

implicit val ConvertibleIndex: Convertible[Index] = new Convertible[Index] {
  def toIndex(i: Index) = i
  def toInteger(i: Index) = i
  def toReal(i: Index) = i.toDouble
}

implicit val ConvertibleInteger: Convertible[Integer] = new Convertible[Integer] {
  def toIndex(i: Integer) = i
  def toInteger(i: Integer) = i
  def toReal(i: Integer) = i.toDouble
}

implicit val ConvertibleReal: Convertible[Real] = new Convertible[Real] {
  def toIndex(r: Real) = r.toInt
  def toInteger(r: Real) = r.toInt
  def toReal(r: Real) = r
}

implicit val ConvertibleString: Convertible[String] = new Convertible[String] {
  def toIndex(s: String) = s.toInt
  def toInteger(s: String) = s.toInt
  def toReal(s: String) = s.toDouble
}

implicit class ConvertibleSyntax[A](a: A)(implicit val c: Convertible[A]) {
  def toIndex = c.toIndex(a)
  def toInteger = c.toInteger(a)
  def toReal = c.toReal(a)
}
```

Consider now:

```
val a = 3.toReal
val b = 3.0.toReal
val c = "3".toReal
```

The statement for `a` does not compile, with the compilation error: `method toReal is not a member of Int`. But, for the `b` and `c` statements, the implicit conversion to `ConvertibleSyntax` is properly done.

Why is the implicit conversion not working on `Int`, but is working on `Double` and `String` ?

Comment: You might try to rewrite `Index` and `Integer` into `AnyVal` classes to disambiguate the implicits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be a little confused about how *Scala* does *implicit conversions*. (A common mistake, as `implicit` is a little overused.)

I think that what you want, first of all, is an *implicit conversion function* - or even an *implicit class*. Here's how you could do this using the latter:

Note: `Int`, `Index` and `Integer` are treated identically, so are `Real` and `Double`, confusing matters somewhat, so I've pared this down to something that will work. Also, `Convertible` does not need to be *generic* as its conversion functions need no arguments. Finally, you shouldn't have both `type` and `val` declarations for your types.

```scala
type Index = Int

type Integer = Int

type Real = Double

trait Convertible {
  def toIndex: Index
  def toInteger: Integer
  def toReal: Real
}

// Implicit classes cannot be defined in top-level scope, so they belong to an object.
object Implicits {

   implicit class ConvertibleInt(i: Int)
   extends Convertible {
     override def toIndex = i
     override def toInteger = i
     override def toReal = i.toDouble
   }

   implicit class ConvertibleDouble(d: Double)
   extends Convertible {
     override def toIndex = d.toInt
     override def toInteger = d.toInt
     override def toReal = d
  }

   implicit class ConvertibleString(s: String)
   extends Convertible {
     override def toIndex = s.toInt
     override def toInteger = s.toInt
     override def toReal = s.toDouble
  }
}
```

Now try this:

```scala
import Implicits._
val a = 3.toReal
val b = 3.0.toReal
val c = "3".toReal
```

What's happening here? Well, the `implicit class` declarations define classes that *decorate* the sole constructor argument with additional functions. If the compiler sees that you're trying to call a method on a type that doesn't have that method, it will look to see if there's an *implicit conversion*, in scope, to a type that does. If so, it is used and the function is called; if not, you get a compiler error. (The `import` statement is used to bring the classes into your current scope.)

So, for example, when the compiler sees `"3".toReal` it firstly determines that `"3"` is a `String`. Since this type doesn't have a `.toReal` member, it tries to find a conversion from a `String` to a type that does have such a member. It finds the `ConvertibleString` *implicit class* that takes a `String` argument and provides a `.toReal` method. Yay! So the compiler creates an instance of this class by passing `"3"` to `ConvertibleString`'s constructor, then calls `.toReal` on the result.

On the other hand, when `implicit` is used with a value, it tells the compiler that the value is a default for any matching *implicit arguments* of the same type that are not provided. **NEVER USE `implicit` WITH A PRIMITIVE OR COMMON LIBRARY TYPE!**

For example:

```scala
final case class Example(i: Int)

// Default.
implicit val nameCanBeAnythingAtAll = Example(5)

// Function with implicit argument.
def someFunc(implicit x: Example): Unit = println(s"Value is $x")
```

Now, if you write something like this:

```scala
someFunc
```

the output will be `Value is Example(5)`.

`implicit` values and arguments are an advanced topic, and I wouldn't worry about how they're used right now.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed explanation. I am reading "Scala with Cats", in which they extend the Scala classes using functors, monads and other category theory concepts.They do this using type classes and the same kind of architecture I wrote in my post. Hence, when I tried to use implicits, I over engineered my implementation.

Comment: The reason I need the val declarations, is to be able to access values such as Real.PositiveInfinity

Answer (score 4):

Because you define ambiguous implicits for `Index` and `Integer` (both `Int`).

Which one should be chosen by compiler?